# vboxmanage createhd - UUID option does not work as expected

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox

So I ran

```
vboxmanage createhd --filename myvm --size 20480
```

Which outputs

> 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100% Medium
>   created. UUID: a3d9562f-113c-4178-9c7f-a4eb37c357f2

The documentation for [`vboxmanage storageattach`](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach) states the `--medium` flag can accept a UUID, however when I run

```
vboxmanage storageattach myvm --storagectl HDD1 --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium a3d9562f-113c-4178-9c7f-a4eb37c357f2
```

It seems Virtualbox does not recognize this is a UUID I'm supplying:

```
VBoxManage: error: The given path 'a3d9562f-113c-4178-9c7f-a4eb37c357f2' is not fully qualified
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 179 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "a3d9562f-113c-4178-9c7f-a4eb37c357f2"
```

Moreover, when I query for the hard drive I allegedly created in the first command above:

```
vboxmanage list hdds
```

there is nothing... So where is the hard drive I created in that command?

Comment: A comment next to a downvote is usually helpful...

Comment: You asked us how to locate a file you created, but didn’t tell us the directory you ran the command in, so that portion of the question couldn’t be answered by anyone (except you).  The error message indicates the command was treating the UUID as the file name which is obviously incorrect (which is not shocking vboxmanage has tons of things that should work but doesn’t actually work)

Comment: I never said, I actually issued a downvote, to this question.  Downvotes are anonymous for a reason, one of those reasons, is to avoid personal attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using absolute paths

```
sudo vboxmanage createmedium disk --filename /var/my-disk-name --size 20480
sudo chown nathan:nathan /var/my-disk-name.vdi 
vboxmanage storageattach myvm --storagectl HDD1 --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium /var/my-disk-name.vdi
```

After this `vboxmanage list hdds` works as expected.

While this works it would still be interesting to know why the UUID option did not work in the first place.

Comment: The documentation makes it clear the reason why the UUID didn’t work, “If a UUID is specified, it must be the UUID of a storage medium that is already known to VirtualBox (e.g. because it has been attached to another virtual machine).”, the virtual drive wasn’t attached to an existing virtual machine based on the first command

Comment: You never attached the virtual HDD to a virtual machine, while a UUID was generated, the documentation makes it clear it must be attached to an existing virtual machine.